# Using tikzcd in newcommand (for inline arrows)

Tags: tikz-pgf, macros, tikz-cd, catcodes, ampersand

I’m using `tikz-cd` for diagrams, and have a medium-sized diagram that I want to re-use several times.  However, when I try using a definition like:

```
\newcommand{\myarrow}{$\begin{tikzcd} A \ar{r} & B \end{tikzcd}$
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR: Package pgfbasematrix Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode.
```

Is it possible to put a `tikz-cd` diagram into a defined command somehow?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's a known problem with TikZ matrices:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\newcommand{\myarrow}{%
  $\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&] A \ar{r} \& B \end{tikzcd}$}
\begin{document}
\myarrow
\end{document}
```

The problem is that `tikzpicture` wants to do some juggling with the meaning of `&`, but it's impossible if the `&` has been found as the replacement text of a macro, as in your original definition. Happily, it provides the

```
ampersand replacement=...
```

key that allows to define some command as substitute for `&`, avoiding the need to do the jugglings.