# tikzcd not working inside \newcommand?

Tags: tikz-cd

Can anyone of you wonderful guys tell why this doesn't work?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,arrows,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\newcommand{\cmd}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}
  \cmd{%
    \[
      \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow{r}{f} & B \\
      \end{tikzcd}
    \]
  }
\end{document}
```

while

```
\[
  \begin{tikzcd}
    A \arrow{r}{f} & B \\
  \end{tikzcd}
\]
```

works perfectly outside the `\cmd`?

Comment: `\begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]` and use `\&` instead of `&`

Comment: Great, it works! (But why the "original" didn't?) Thank you!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved in the first comment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using tikzcd in newcommand (for inline arrows)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87781/using-tikzcd-in-newcommand-for-inline-arrows)